# Blade is echoing 1

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, var-dump

I am trying to echo result of a function using blade `{!! !!}`

Using like this `{!! !!}` It shows the value that I need besides of showing 1
I have var dumped the function doing like this

```
{!! var_dump(ma_fonction)!!}
```

It shows me the result and after it , it shows `bool(true)`

Does anyone has an idea about this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add more code, what should `ma_fonction` actually return according to you?

Comment: I tis returning a widget in wordpress

Comment: can you paste the output from `@dd(ma_function)` ? in your question, please!

Comment: text (content of widget)
-- and after that --
^ true

Comment: There is btw no need of the {!! !!} just use normal {{ }}.

Answer (score 0):

its because of default behaviour of `var_dump` function.
learn more [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

you could also consider [var_export](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

Comment: I have used var_dump for test -_-

Answer (score 0):

Very likely your function returns an array. And probably the last field in the array is a key => bool.  For exapmple:

`array(5) { ["description"]=> string(6) "<b>a</b>" ["isSomething"]=> string(4) "true" }`

If you want print the description the use:

```php
@php $data = ma_function(); @endphp
{!! $data['description'] !!}
```